# TargetNullValue=n/a based on another columns Value

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, devexpress

I have a DevEx GridView which is bonded to a data table I have one column the user has to enter a date when he sent an ASN but not all orders require one so I've another column in the data table (not in the grid) with a bool value(true or null, my data table supports null values) if it is required or not, what i want do do is if required is = null then on the date column in the gridview it should say "n\a"
I tried the following but its not working:

```
   <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="ASN_SENT" Name="gridColumn14" Validate="gridColumn14_Validate"   Header="ASN Sent">
                <dxg:GridColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style  TargetType="{x:Type dxg:CellContentPresenter}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=RowData.Row.ASN_Req}" Value="Null">

                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="N/A"/>
                            </DataTrigger>

                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </dxg:GridColumn.CellStyle>
                </dxg:GridColumn>
```

Comment: and if you change Null to `{x:Null}` ?

Comment: Thanx for replying I tried and it didn't work, what i tried and did work is setting the background property  <Setter Property="Background" Value="red" /> and it did work even without the change to {x:Null}